# How Do you map a multi argument function to a list of numbers

Tags: ocaml

So I am trying to map a function that has 3 arguments, 2 are give and the list of number which would be the last variable. I use my map function but I will not work and im not sure why. I works if the function passed in has 2 arguments. I tried to look for other solutions and havent found much Im not sure but should I try it recursively?

```
let segment (cx,cy) (nx,ny) =
    let lnf = range (cx+1) nx in
    let s = slope (cx,cy) (nx,ny) in
    let y = yintercept (cx,cy) in
    map (solve s y) lnf;;

let slope (x1,y1) (x2,y2) : int =
  (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

let yintercept ((x1,y1):coord) slope: int =
    (y1 - (slope * x1))

let solve (m:int) (b:int) (x:int)=
    (x*m)+b

let rec map: ('a -> 'b)  -> 'a list -> 'b list = fun f l ->
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> f h ::  map f t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
let y = yintercept (cx,cy) in
```

You're calling `yintercept` with just one argument. But the function expects two arguments. So the returned value is a function of one argument. The rest of your code assumes that `y` is an `int` (not a function).